# access jsp param in java code block

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a param, say **someVar** that is accessible in jsp block by using **${someVar}**. I'm wondering how to get this value in java code block <% %>. I tried

```
<%
  String str = request.getParameter("someVar");
%>
```

and str is null. How can I get **someVar** within <% %> block? Thanks.

Comment: What is the scope of 'someVar'?

Comment: somVar is passed from the xml template. I dont know what its scope is. I tried <% Object obj = pageContext.getAttribute("someVar", .... ); %> where ... is 4 different copes and always got null back.

Answer (score 0):

Using Implicit Object **PageContext**

Either this way

```
  <% Object obj = pageContext.getAttribute("someVar"); %>
```

or this way

```
  <% Object obj = pageContext.getAttribute("someVar",pageContext.SCOPE); %>
```

The diffrent scopes are

```
pageScope   it maps the given attribute name with the value set in the page scope
requestScope    it maps the given attribute name with the value set in the request scope
sessionScope    it maps the given attribute name with the value set in the session scope
applicationScope    it maps the given attribute name with the value set in the application scope
```

Comment: Thanks. If I just use your code (with all four types of scope), I still got a null obj. If I add <c:set var="someVar" value="${someVar}" /> before the <% %> block then pageContext.getAttribute("someVar") returns correct value. Do you know why <c:set... is needed ?